# Не правильно работает программа ассемблер masm

Tags: ассемблер, masm, dos

есть программа которая встраивает пользовательский обработчик прерываний в стандартный обработчик от клавиатуры.
Дело в том, что на моём пк, запускаю программу через DOSbox она работает корректно, весь ещё функционал в том, что она заменяет цифры 1,2, ... 9, 0  на символы !, @, #,... ,(,)

Но при проверке преподавателем, на его ПК она работает не правильно, возможно сам обработчик прерывания написан не так, поймать ошибку просто нет возможности, т.к у меня она работает не зависая

Скрин того, где она работает неверно ниже

[image: Программа у препода]

> После 1 долго ждет на 2, а затем висит (это от преподавателя)

Вопрос к знающим, в чём может быть проблема такой неоднозначности работы

Скрин работы у меня в DOSbox ниже, ввожу оба раза 1234567890 [image: Работа у меня на ПК в DOSbox]

Код самого обработчика ниже

```
    MY_RES PROC far
    
    jmp body
   
    PSP dw ?
    KEEP_IP dw 0
    KEEP_CS dw 0
    INT_TAG dw 1234h
   
    KEEP_SS dw ?
    KEEP_SP dw ?
    KEEP_AX dw ?
    MY_RES_STACK dw 64 dup (?)
    END_STACK dw ?
   
body:
   mov KEEP_SS,ss
   mov KEEP_SP,sp
   mov KEEP_AX,ax

   mov ax,cs
   mov ss,ax
   mov sp,offset END_STACK

   push bx
   push cx
   push dx
   
   in al,60h

   cmp al,02h ; 1
   jne metkaf2
   mov cl, '!' ;1-> !
   jmp next

metkaf2:
   cmp al,03h ; 2
   jne metkaf3
   mov cl, '@' ;2-> @
   jmp next

metkaf3:
   cmp al,04h ;  3
   jne metkaf4
   mov cl, '#' ;3-> #
   jmp next

metkaf4:
   cmp al,05h ;  4
   jne metkaf5
   mov cl, '$' ; 4-> $ 
   jmp next

metkaf5:
   cmp al,06h ;  5
   jne metkaf6
   mov cl, '%' ; 5-> %
   jmp next

metkaf6:
   cmp al,07h ; 6
   jne metkaf7
   mov cl, '^' ; 6-> ^
   jmp next

metkaf7:
   cmp al,08h ; 7
   jne metkaf8
   mov cl, '&' ; 7-> &
   jmp next

metkaf8:
   cmp al,09h ; 8
   jne metkaf9
   mov cl, '*' ; 8-> *
   jmp next

metkaf9:
   cmp al,0Ah ; 9
   jne metkaf10
   mov cl, '(' ; 9-> (
   jmp next

metkaf10:
   cmp al,0Bh ; 10
   jne fall
   mov cl, ')' ; 10-> )
   jmp next

fall:
   call dword ptr cs:KEEP_IP
   jmp to_quit
   
next:
   in al,61h
    mov ah, al    
    or al, 80h    
    out 61h, al  
    xchg ah, al    
    out 61h, al    
    mov al, 20h     
    out 20h, al  
   
print_sym:
   mov ah,05h
   mov ch,00h
   int 16h
   or al,al
   jnz pass

   jmp to_quit
   
pass:
   mov ax,0C00h
   int 21h
   jmp print_sym

to_quit:
   
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
   
    mov ax, KEEP_SS
    mov ss, ax
    mov ax, KEEP_AX
    mov sp, KEEP_SP

   iret
my_res_end:
MY_RES ENDP
```

Что может быть не так?

Comment: давно известно, что клаву перехватывает в любых ситуация `INT-15h AH=4F`

Answer (score 0):

Вызывают сомнения следующие команды:

```
mov KEEP_SS,ss    
mov KEEP_SP,sp    
mov KEEP_AX,ax
```

Эти команды подразумевают, что регистр ds указывает на сегмент кода обработчика (туда же, куда и cs). А разве это так? При возникновении прерывания ds может указывать куда угодно, но вовсе не на сегмент кода обработчика.
Следует попробовать явно указать сегментный регистр:

```
mov cs:KEEP_SS,ss
mov cs:KEEP_SP,sp
mov cs:KEEP_AX,ax
```

Так же измените и команды восстановления регистров:

```
mov ax, cs:KEEP_SS    
mov ss, ax    
mov ax, cs:KEEP_AX    
mov sp, cs:KEEP_SP
```

Кроме того, вы вызываете из обработчика прерывания службу DOS:

```
mov ax,0C00h
int 21h
jmp print_sym
```

Без специальных мер это недопустимо. Пробуйте вместо этого выводить символ на экран через int 10h либо непосредственно, записью в видеопамять.

P.S. Да, а что вообще делает вызов int 21h при ax=0C00h? Это что-то нестандартное? Если это так, то, возможно, оно поддерживается не во всех ядрах dos.